# Creating a new VSTO add-in tab instead of renaming

Tags: vsto

We have a MS word addin that currently uses and renames the add-in tab in Word (to i-report).
The problem with this is that if clients have other addins installed, the ribbons from their addins also appear under the i-report tab.

Is there an easy way to use a new tab exclusively instead of renaming the add-ins tab?

The code for the tab in the designer looks like this:

```
        this.tabiReport = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab();
        this.tabiReport.SuspendLayout();

        this.tabiReport.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
        this.tabiReport.Groups.Add(this.grpConnection);         
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tabiReport, "tabiReport");
        this.tabiReport.Name = "tabiReport";
```

**EDIT:** I assume this has something to do with the position of the Tabs collection for the Ribbon. I have tried changing the position of tabiReport from default to BeforeOfficeId and AfterOfficeId but then when debugging I can see the addin load at start up but there is no tab on the ribbon.

I have also tried using AfterOfficeId and then populating the OfficeId field with "TabView
" to try get it to display after the view tab but it still doesn't show. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Ok I have figured out how this is supposed to be done: By setting the ControlIdType property to custom on the tab but I still have the same problem of it not showing up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this was to set the ControlIdType to custom.

If the position property is set to Default the tab will appear last in the list.

To change the position of the tab you can change the PositionType to BeforeOfficeId (or AfterOfficeId) and populate the OfficeId with the Id of the tab that you want it to appear before or after (eg TabView).

A Full list of office tab Ids can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627)

Comment: Yup, I eventually found this solution aswell.  Make sure your RibbonTab is selected in the designer, expand the "ControlID" property, then change the "ControlIDType" from Office to Custom.  Utterly bonkers... that's just bad design in VS2010.  Having each Addin in it's own Tab should come as standard.

Comment: you'll have more power if you used RibbonXML

Answer (score 0):

Instead of designing the TabAddIns tab, how about adding a Tab in Office Ribbon Controls to the OfficeRibbonButton? We could change the name of the added tab to i-report.